# Using MUI Palette Color When Creating Typography Variant

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently using Material UI React 5.11.3.

Currently, to specify that I want to use the `text.secondary` color, I need to specify it in the color prop each time I use the caption variant:

```
<Typography variant="caption" color="text.secondary">
  Text
</Typography>
```

To avoid repeating myself, I would like to set up a Typography variant named "caption" that references the MUI palette color `text.secondary`. Currently, however, the `color` attribute in the TypographyOptions only supports CSS colors (so `color: red` would work, for example).

--

So, ideally, I want to reference the MUI palette theme when defining the caption variant:

```
export const typography: TypographyOptions = {
  caption: {
    fontSize: '0.875rem',
    color: 'text.secondary'
  },
}
```

```
export interface Text {
  fontSize: string;
  color: string;
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface TypographyVariants {
    caption: Text;
  }

  interface TypographyVariantsOptions {
    caption: Text;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MUI [document](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/), `theme` can be composed in steps when an option is depending on another option, which could be used for defining the `variant` needed in the use case.

Example: (quick experiment demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wnihth?file=src/App.js))

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { pink, teal } from '@mui/material/colors';

let theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    text: {
      primary: {
        main: pink[500],
      },
      secondary: {
        main: teal[300],
      },
    },
  },
});

theme = createTheme(theme, {
  typography: {
    caption: {
      fontSize: '0.875rem',
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary.main,
    },
    h4: {
      color: theme.palette.text.primary.main,
    },
  },
});
```